# VBA comparing variants

Tags: vba, excel

What I was going to do was iterate through the variants to see if everything inside matches.

...But is there a quicker and more efficient way to compare variants? (I don't really need to know what is inside it.)

If I was comparing between strings "If string1 = string2 Then ..." would suffice. (in this case would be somehting like "If Var1 = Var2 Then ....").

```
Var1 = Sheets(1).Range("A1:B10")
Var2 = Sheets(1).Range("C1:D10")


    A      B      C     D
   ABC    DEF    ABC   DEF  
   SBC    SEF    SBC   SEF  
   FBC    FEF    FBC   FEF  
   RBC    REF    RBC   REF
```

The data will be mostly text and most of the times Col A and B should be equal to Col C and D (in the specified number of rows in the range). What I need to know is if the columns A and B (in the specified rows) have the same content as D and C.

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: I still haven't coded it. For now I just have 2 variants with the values from 2  ranges [   Var1 = Sheets(1).Range("A1:B10") : Var2 = Sheets(1).Range("C1:D10")    ]

Comment: you should specify what kind of comparission are you doing, and what type of input could be in those ranges. are you looking for identity between them? (i.e. var1 has the same values as var2 and they are ordered the same), looking for both having the same values, but not in the same order? it can change how fast you can deduce the answer

Comment: so it seems you need to have exactly the same value,(i.e. A1 needs to be equal to C1 etc.) that way you can't avoid explicit comparission, you have to iterate over the whole this as Jeeped suggested, otherwise you might get false positive, although i would add a break in the case that you get a false on the compare, that way you don't need to continue checking once you know it's not good.

Comment: Yes, all I need is to know whether the text in one range (A1:B10) is the same as the text in the other range (C1:D10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straightforward solution (first I thought of). Runs in ~0.12 milliseconds:

```
oRange1 = Range("A1:B10")
oRange2 = Range("C1:D10")

For i = 1 To 10
    For j = 1 To 2
        If oRange1(i, j) <> oRange2(i, j) Then MsgBox "Not equal.": Exit For
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're trying to compare two ranges as you've mentioned in your comment, i would suggest iterating over the first range `rng1` with a `for each` loop, and using `MATCH` to see if each of the items in `rng1` is in `rng2`, that would be faster then comparing explicitly each pair.

Comment: Indeed that would be faster. I hadn't thought about using formulas, but they may be the best for this.

Comment: match is applicable also in VBA, not only in forumlas in excel, so if it's part of a bigger macro it's not a problem

`x = worksheetfunction.Match(arg1,arg2,arg3)`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at two @ 2-dimensional arrays.

This short routine spits out the dimensions ([LBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) and [UBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx)) and the values to the VBE's Immediate window (Ctrl+G).

```
Sub str_test()
    Dim v As Long, w As Long, vABs As Variant, vCDs As Variant

    With ActiveSheet
        vABs = .Range("A1:B10").Value2
        vCDs = .Range("C1:D10").Value2
        Debug.Print LBound(vABs, 1) & ":" & UBound(vABs, 1)
        Debug.Print LBound(vABs, 2) & ":" & UBound(vABs, 2)
        Debug.Print LBound(vCDs, 1) & ":" & UBound(vCDs, 1)
        Debug.Print LBound(vCDs, 2) & ":" & UBound(vCDs, 2)

        For v = LBound(vABs, 1) To UBound(vABs, 1)
            For w = LBound(vABs, 2) To UBound(vABs, 2)
                Debug.Print vABs(v, w) & " - " & vCDs(v, w)
            Next w
        Next v
    End With
End Sub
```

Results:

```
str_test
1:10
1:2
1:10
1:2
LOGG - JWSA
EGXL - SBQI
WKSL - ZITO
VUKB - MCWY
(etc, etc, blah, blah...)
```

You should be able to make your string comparisons from there.

Comment: Interesting. That is more complex than what I was hoping for (even seems more complex than an iteration), but it sure looks tidy! I'll try to understand a bit better what it is actually doing (or rather how it is doing what it is doing). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to compare two identically shaped ranges and their values are numbers, you can use (in VBA) the worksheet function `SumX2MY2(A, B)`. This function calculates the squares of the differences between the corresponding entries. The numbers are identical if and only if the result is 0. This probably isn't the most efficient approach -- but for large arrays it *might* win out (in virtue of using Excel's calculation engine rather than interpreted VBA code). You could use it something like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim A As Variant, B As Variant
    A = Range("A1:B2").Value
    B = Range("C1:D2").Value
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.SumX2MY2(A, B) = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Values the same"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Values different"
    End If   
End Sub
```

Run it twice, once when the two ranges contain identical values and once when some of the values differ.

On Edit: If you want to compare two ranges which contain text for equality and you don't want to use nested loops, you can use an array formula. Pick a cell, say `X1` which you don't plan on using (hide it to be safe) and create a function like this:

```
Function SameVals(R1 As Range, R2 As Range) As Boolean
    Range("X1").FormulaArray = "= Sum(If(" & _
                               R1.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & _
                               "=" & R2.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & _
                               ",0,1))"
    SameVals = Range("X1").Value = 0
    Range("X1").ClearContents
End Function
```

Test it like thus:

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox SameVals(Range("A1:B4"), Range("C1:D4"))
End Sub
```

In the test case the array formula

```
{= SUM(IF($A$1:$B$4=$C$1:$D$4,0,1)}
```

is assembled in X1. It first creates an array of 0's and 1's indicating positions where the ranges differ and then sums this result.

This has drawbacks compared to the obvious nested for loop approach to checking ranges for equality, but if you are testing large ranges for equality and performance of the straightforward iterative approach seems to be an issue you could experiment with this approach.

Comment: The range will contain mostly text... But I'm thinking that some match function on the variants may do the trick.

Comment: @jony I added a second approach which works for text, although I am skeptical that it is really better than the straightforward iterative approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the formula approach (without VBA):

[image: Using Match formula]

---

Another way to quickly highlight differences with formulas:

```
 A       B       C       D       E           F
ABC     DEF     ABC      x      TRUE        FALSE
SBC     SEF     SBC     SEF     TRUE        TRUE
FBC     FEF     FBC     FEF     TRUE        TRUE
RBC     REF     RBC     REF     TRUE        TRUE

ABC     DEF     ABC     DEF     =A7=C7      =B7=D7
SBC     SEF     SBC     SEF     =A8=C8      =B8=D8
FBC     FEF     FBC     FEF     =A9=C9      =B9=D9
RBC     REF     RBC     REF     =A10=C10    =B10=D10
```

---

This is the Match function in VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub compareValues()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Variant, rng3 As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet, result As Variant, cel As Range

    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set rng1 = ws.Range("A1:B10")
    rng2 = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("C1:C10"))
    rng3 = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("D1:D10"))

    For Each cel In rng1
        cel = Trim(cel)
        If Len(cel) > 0 Then
            result = Application.Match(cel, rng2, 0)
            If IsError(result) Then
                result = Application.Match(cel, rng3, 0)
                If IsError(result) Then cel.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm more inexperienced with formulas than with VBA, but isn't there a formula which returns a single true/false value for if Range1 contains the same exact text as the Range2? That would solve it quick and easy. Like a match inside a match?